# Sequelize include association in WHERE query

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I have the following query to search for users on the `User` model:

```
const users = await User.findAndCountAll({
    limit: 20,
    offset: 20 * page,
    attributes: {
        include: [[literal('`discord_user.username`'), 'username']]
    },
    order: [['email', 'ASC']],
    where: {
        [Op.or]: [
            {email: {[Op.like]: '%' + query + '%'}},
            {full_name: {[Op.like]: '%' + query + '%'}},
        ]
    },
    include: [
        {model: Licence},
        {
            model: DiscordUser,
            as: "discord_user",
        }
    ]
});
```

I have done a join to the `DiscordUser` model as seen in the include parameter. However, I want to include a `LIKE` query on the `DiscordUser.username` field in my `WHERE` query.

The pseudo code I have come up with to demonstrate what I'm after looks something like:

```
where: {
    [Op.or]: [
        {email: {[Op.like]: '%' + query + '%'}},
        {full_name: {[Op.like]: '%' + query + '%'}},
        DiscordUser.username LIKE query

    ]
}
```

I've associated `DiscordUser` to `User` like so:

`User.belongsTo(DiscordUser, {as: 'discord_user'})`

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Simply use the syntax with wrapping `$` characters to indicated a field from associated model in the main `where` conditions:

````js
where: {
        [Op.or]: [
            {email: {[Op.like]: '%' + query + '%'}},
            {full_name: {[Op.like]: '%' + query + '%'}},
            { '$discord_user.username$': {[Op.like]: '%' + query + '%'}},
        ]
    },```
````

Comment: I tried this, however I get an error: `symbol discord_user.username not found`, despite the fact that I have included the reference to the model. `username` also definitely exists on the `DiscordUser` model

Comment: I actually got your suggestion to work by adding `subQuery: false` to my outermost query.

Comment: Yes, sometimes it's useful to turn off `subQuery` option and often you will get more simple and straight-forward SQL query